# Draw SVG using QML

Tags: qt, qml

How can I draw a SVG using qml in simple words?

According to QtDocs it is possible to draw a SVG using this code:

```
Path {
    startX: 50; startY: 50
    PathSvg { path: "L 150 50 L 100 150 z" }
}
```

But actually it doesn't.
So, how can I draw SVG?

Comment: Reading the documentation carefully could help to solve many problems. For example the docs of [Path](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-path.html#details) says: _Note: Path is a non-visual type; it does not display anything on its own. To draw a path, use Shape_

Comment: @folibis but that's just Path, not SVG path, and you know what SVG stands for - scalable vector **graphics**, not data ;)

Comment: Sure, but TC wants `Path` as I understand so I've just pointed him to the right way :) As for me I would use `Image` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in the documentation says anything about drawing. It says "defines a path" by using SVG path syntax.

Drawing it is a different step:

```
Canvas {
    width: 400; height: 200
    contextType: "2d"

    onPaint: {
        context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(.4,.6,.8)
        context.path = yourPath
        context.stroke()
    }
}
```

Note that as long as Qt is compiled with SVG support you can directly use .svg files as image sources.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to show a path, you must use it within a `Shape`:

```
Shape {
    ShapePath {
        fillColor: "red"
        strokeWidth: 2
        strokeColor: "blue"
        startX: 50; startY: 50
        PathSvg { path: "L 150 50 L 100 150 z" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having great success using inline SVG in data-uri as follows:

```
    Image {
        source:
`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
<path fill="orange" stroke="royalblue" d="L 150 50 L 100 150 z" />
</svg>`
    }
```

[image: triangle-svg]

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?code=import%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0A%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Image%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20source%3A%0A%60data%3Aimage%2Fsvg%2Bxml%3Butf8%2C%0A%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20150%20150%22%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22orange%22%20stroke%3D%22royalblue%22%20d%3D%22L%20150%2050%20L%20100%20150%20z%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%60%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)